# Remove an image brought up by on mouseover

Tags: javascript

The following script opens an image onmouseover, however I can't come up with a way to remove the image onmouseout. I know I am missing something extremely simple but can't seem to find something that works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(Id) {
    document.getElementById(Id).style.display="inline";
    }
    </script>    
    <span onmouseover="show ('myImage')">- <u>LAZARETTE</u></span></b>
    <img src="../images/MarkILineDrawingLazarette.jpg" id="myImage" border="0" style="display:none;"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function hide(Id) {
    document.getElementById(Id).style.display="none";
}
```

then change the opening span tag to:

```
<span onmouseover="show('myImage')" onmouseout="hide('myImage')" >
```

Edit:
[JSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/evtSc/1/)

Comment: And then add `onmouseout="hide('myImage')"` to your `<span>`.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close!  Just add the onmouseout event!

### HTML

```
<b>   
<span onmouseover="show('myImage',true)" onmouseout="show('myImage',false)">- <u>LAZARETTE</u></span></b>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
function show(Id, show) {
    document.getElementById(Id).style.display = show ? "inline" : "None";
}
```